# Get objectives Google FIT Rest API

Tags: google-fit

I am trying to get users' objectives through the rest API, for Google Fit.
While I know this exists for Android: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/GoalsClient

I am not aware (after browsing for hours) of such methods/entrypoint for the rest API.
Could someone point me to the right ressource/direction?

Thanks

Comment: This is not exposed via the REST API.

Comment: The class is deprecated now. For reading and writing historical fitness data use Health Connect. You may also file a feature request if needed.